# State not updating when using react hooks and progressCallback from Amplify Storage.put function

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am attempting to use the Amplify Storage progressCallback function to add a visual indicator of upload progress but I am unable to update the state from inside the progressCallback function. The code below runs without any errors but fails to update the loading hook.

I believe this is an issue with how i am trying to pass the state to the  callBack function, but if this is the case i am not sure what the solution is. Would love some help.

```
const CustomCard = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);

  const CustomFunc = progress => {
    setLoading(progress);
    console.log(loading);
  };

  const onChange = async e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const fileName = "test";
    const result = await Storage.put(fileName, file, {
      customPrefix: { public: "public/" },
      progressCallback: progress => {
        CustomFunc(progress.progress);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <input
           id="add-image-file-input"
           type="file"
           accept="image/*."
           onChange={onChange}
           style={{ display: "none" }}
       />
       <FileUploadProgress loading={loading} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: You're defining `result` seemingly for no reason. Try writing it as `await Storage.put` without attaching it to a variable.

Comment: Also I would try changing `onChange()` from an async function to a regular function and remove `await`.

Comment: Yes, intentions were to use `async()` later as well as the `result`, removing them did not make any changes.

Comment: I would put `progress.progress` in a `console.log()` before `CustomFunc()` is called just to check that it's passing in what you expect.

Comment: Hi Joss, yes it is passing what I would expect. It is sort of strange as what i have noticed is that the the `progressCallback` function will not catch any errors. That being said i can use `try catch`  in the `CustomFunc` to do so. The code above currently does not cause any errors, and i can confirm through a quick `console.log` test that the `progress.progess` value is appearing in the `CustomFunc`

Comment: That's odd. Are you absolutely sure that the value of `loading` is not changing and it's not a problem with `<FileUploadProgress />`? Maybe put a `console.log(loading)` after `setLoading()` has been called. Another possible solution would be to move the code into the callback function. `progressCallback: progress => setLoading(progress.progress)`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you that did it. I did make a mistake with publishing my question of `progress.progress` instead of `progress.loaded` but it appears that `progress => setLoading(progress.loaded)` worked. Thank you so much for your help.